# How to set a dataTable columns names to the alphabets in order

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datatable

I have a dataTable which i have set the number of columns and rows to a loop of 500 rows and columns using the following code!

```
DataTable custTable = new DataTable("Customers");
            DataColumn dtColumn;
            DataRow myDataRow;

            for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            {
                custTable.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
                myDataRow = custTable.NewRow();
                custTable.Rows.Add(myDataRow);
            }
```

however, as you might be able to see, the columns name is set to `""` which will give me the result of `Column1, Column2, ...` but i want it to be set to the alphabetical order of like `A, B, C, D, ...`

I tried using an array to set the names but it doesn`t accept arrays only strings.

Comment: `Char.ConvertFromUtf32(i)`

Answer (score 1):

This code creates a table with `column names A to Z`:

```
for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++)
{
   custTable.Columns.Add(c.ToString() ,typeof(string));
}
```